# How to add preset text into the content box using JCE?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, interaction, joomla-content-editor

Using Joomla! 1.5.26 and JCE 2.1.3, the users can select several options (strings) from a popup and those options should be directly insert text in the JCE textarea where the cursor is.

How can I interact with the JCE content without creating a plugin?

Comment: may I just say thank you. You must be the first person I have seen on here who is using the most up to date version of Joomla 1.5 :)

Comment: This question was posted before [joomla.se] Stack Exchange was born.  Please post all Joomla questions in this dedicated Stack Exchange community to receive support from volunteers with a more intimate knowledge of the CMS and its extensions.  Since you answered your own question, you might like to migrate this page  to JSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<strong>whatever you want!!!!</strong>');
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on any Stack Exchange site.  Please always explain to the best of your ability how your solutions works.  This post would probably help more people if you explained where you write this line of code.